# RxJava: Publish subject doOnSubscribe never gets called

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I want to implement a simple scenario where a certain action will take place when an observer subscribes to a PublishSubject.

I implemented it like this:

```
PublishSubject<String>publishSubject=PublishSubject.create();
                publishSubject.doOnSubscribe(new Action0() {
                    @Override
                    public void call() {
                        //do something
                    }
                });

                publishSubject.subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(String s) {

                }
            });
                publishSubject.onNext("xyz");
```

The problem is that the Action0.call method never gets called.

Is there something wrong here? or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each operator on `Observable` returns another `Observable` - it's not changing state it's creating a new one. So instead of subscribing to the observable that executes action on subscription time, You just subscribed to the subject.

Just do

```
publishSubject
    .doOnSubscribe(() -> doSmth())
    .subscribe();
```